# Using Limits to get index name pandas data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, limits

I have upper and lower limits for data sets and i would like to be able to pull out the index (preferably in a list) for any items falling outside of this:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  1  7  6  0  7  3  0  0  8
2  4  8  3  4  9  6  3  2  3
3  3  7  5  5  7  5  1  1  4
4  2  6  2  1  3  9  4  3  9
5 10  2  2  6  4  7  4  9  7

#Have another data frame with our limits
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  1  7  3  4  7  3  0  0  3
2  4  8  9 10  9  6  3  2  8
```

So I would want to get the index 1,4,5 since at some point they fall out of my limits.

I can use this:

```
llCheck = data < ll
hlCheck = data > hl

llCheck = 
X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9
False False False True  False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False
False True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
True  True  True  False True  True  True  True  False
```

and get two data frames that contain true/false values for each cell which i think is helpful, but havent been able to get further and get the index if any item in the row = true.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need filter `index` values with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
ll = 0
hl = 2

m = (df > ll) & (df < hl)
L = df.index[m.any(axis=1)].tolist()
print (L)
[1, 3, 4]
```

Explanation:

```
#get mask by limits with chaining both conditions
m = (df > ll) & (df < hl)
print (m)
      X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9
1   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False   True   True  False
4  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False

#check if at least one True per row
print (m.any(axis=1))
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool

#is possible filter rows
print (df[m.any(axis=1)])
   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9
1   1   7   6   0   7   3   0   0   8
3   3   7   5   5   7   5   1   1   4
4   2   6   2   1   3   9   4   3   9
```